# How can I fix the error of "MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery."?

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know why this error comes out when I use "Tab" like below. Whenever I tried to build the app
the error screen comes out. Please let me know how to fix it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Tab'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.tag_faces),),
              Tab(text: 'menu',),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info),text: 'menu',),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(color: Colors.purple,),
            Container(color: Colors.purple,),
            Container(color: Colors.purple,),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use [MaterialApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) widget as the root of your widget tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap DefaultTabController in MaterialApp. If you visit the [Scaffold](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart#L386) class then you can see that it needs MediaQuery. MediaQuery is defined in [WidgetsApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsApp-class.html) class. Since the MaterialApp inherits from WidgetsApp hence wrapping our widget tree will allow the Scaffold to access MediaQuery class.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Tab'),
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: <Widget>[
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.tag_faces),),
                Tab(text: 'menu',),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info),text: 'menu',),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(color: Colors.purple,),
              Container(color: Colors.purple,),
              Container(color: Colors.purple,),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it works well!! thank you very much for your explanation!!!